# How can I get the variable to be set to show something outside the method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, openlayers

Good day my friends.

I got a variable set in the data of vue:

```
var comp=
{
    data()
    {
        return{
            polygonString:""
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I want to set the 'polygonString' inside the method of 'modifyend' it stays blank when doing a console.log() outside the method:

```
methods:{
     addCoordinate(){
         modify.on('modifyend', function (evt) {

            var flat_coords;
            var modified_coords = [];

            evt.features.forEach(function (feature) {
            flat_coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();

            for (var i in flat_coords) 
            {
                var flat_coord = flat_coords[i];
                for(var coord_array in flat_coord)
                {
                    var lat_lng = flat_coord[coord_array];
                    var transformed_coords = ol.proj.transform(lat_lng,'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326');
                                
                    modified_coords.push(transformed_coords.toString().replace(",", " "));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    this.polygonString = modified_coords.toString().replaceAll(",", ", ");
        });
        console.log("POLYGON STRING", this.polygonString);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registering the `modifyend` event listener inside a method seems like it will be problematic. You should probably move the registration logic to one of the lifecycle hooks, `mounted` or `created`.

Try making the following changes:

```
mounted() {
  modify.on('modifyend', this.addCoordinate);
},
methods: {
  addCoordinate(evt) {
    var flat_coords;
    var modified_coords = [];

    evt.features.forEach(function(feature) {
      flat_coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();

      for (var i in flat_coords) {
        var flat_coord = flat_coords[i];
        for (var coord_array in flat_coord) {
          var lat_lng = flat_coord[coord_array];
          var transformed_coords = ol.proj.transform(lat_lng, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
          modified_coords.push(transformed_coords.toString().replace(",", " "));
        }
      }
    });
      
    this.polygonString = modified_coords.toString().replaceAll(",", ", ");

    console.log("POLYGON STRING", this.polygonString);
  }
}
```